# It's working diffently in react while using and not using braces in arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

this is another geek here. I am learning reactjs now. I found this in my code while I was tring to create a `Button` element for my app. My idea is to decide background color according to a `prop` called `type`. This is similar to a switch case. please go through the code to find problem.

```
const colors = {
  primary: "#0d6efd",
  secondary: "#adb5bd",
  success: "#198754",
  info: "#0dcaf0",
  warning: "#ffc107",
  danger: "#dc3545",
  light: "#f8f9fa",
  dark: "#212529",
};

let bg = ((cl) => {
    colors[cl] || "#adb5bd";
})("primary");

let bg2 = ((cl) => colors[cl] || "#adb5bd")(type);

console.log(bg, bg2);
```

In console,

`undefined '#adb5bd'`

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is so obvious. When we use curly braces, it doesn't returns anything implicitly. But it returns the expression if used without braces.

```js
const colors = {
  primary: "#0d6efd",
  secondary: "#adb5bd",
  success: "#198754",
  info: "#0dcaf0",
  warning: "#ffc107",
  danger: "#dc3545",
  light: "#f8f9fa",
  dark: "#212529",
};

let bg = ((cl) => {
    colors[cl] || "#adb5bd"; <-------
})("primary");

let bg2 = ((cl) => colors[cl] || "#adb5bd")("primary");

console.log(bg, bg2);
```

The pointed out line works as an expression and it will return something when explicitily written.

```js
let bg = ((cl) => {
    return colors[cl] || "#adb5bd"; //returns "#0d6efd"
})("primary");
```

Read this article on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#description).

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything from your function. When you use curly brackets notation while writing a function you need to return explicitly.

```js
let bg = ((cl) => {
    return colors[cl] || "#adb5bd";
})("primary");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything.You can use

```js
let bg = ((cl) =>  colors[cl] || "#adb5d")("primary");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do is something like:

```
const Button = (props) => {
  const { type = 'primary' } = props; // we get the type with destructuring
  const colors = {
    primary: "#0d6efd",
    secondary: "#adb5bd",
    success: "#198754",
    info: "#0dcaf0",
    warning: "#ffc107",
    danger: "#dc3545",
    light: "#f8f9fa",
    dark: "#212529",
  };
  const color = colors[type];
  return <button style={{backgroundColor: color}}>I am the button with random color</button>
}
```